# Is there any discernible difference to using an exception handler that rethrows the exception

Tags: java, exception, optimization

Given a function that might throw:

```
public static int f() throws Exception {
    // do something
}
```

Is there any way this code:

```
public static int catchF() throws Exception {
    try {
        return f();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

is any different to calling `f` directly? I.e. could the caller detect the difference by inspecting the exception? Is there any discernible overhead in using `catchF` instead of `f`?

If there is no difference, can compilers, or the JVM, optimise a call to `catchF` into a direct call to `f`?

While this might seem like a strange thing to do, the use case would be to re-introduce an exception at the type level after earlier hiding it:

```
class Test {

    // Hide the exception.
    public static <X extends Exception, T> T throwUnchecked(Exception ex) throws X {
        throw (X) ex;
    }

    // Interface for functions which throw.
    interface Throws<T, R, X extends Exception> {
        R apply(T t) throws X;
    }


    // Convert a function which throws a visible exception into one that throws a hidden exception.
    public static <T, R, X extends Exception> Function<T, R> wrap(Throws<T, R, X> thrower) {
        return t -> {
            try {
                return thrower.apply(t);
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                return throwUnchecked(ex);
            }
        };
    }

    // Unhide an exception.
    public static <R, X extends Exception> R unwrap(Supplier<R> supp) throws X {
        try {
            return supp.get();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw (X)ex;
        }
    }

    public static Stream<Integer> test(Stream<String> ss) throws NumberFormatException {
        return Test.<Stream<Integer>, NumberFormatException>unwrap(
                () -> ss.map(wrap(Integer::parseInt))
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException {
        final List<Integer> li = test(Arrays.stream(new String[]{"1", "2", "3"})).collect(toList());
        System.out.println(li);
    }
}
```

The intent is to wrap functions that throw exception into ones where the exception is hidden at the type level. This makes the exceptions usable for example with streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is any different to calling f directly?

No.

> I.e. could the caller detect the difference by inspecting the exception?

No, because you're not constructing a new exception at this point. The stack trace was constructed at the point where the `new WhateverException(...)` was invoked (*not* where the `throw` was, although they are often in the same place).

Typically, you rethrow a caught exception if you need to do some cleanup as a result of the exception:

```
try {
  // ...
} catch (SomeException e) {
  // Clean up resources.
  throw e;
}
```

The fact that something happened as the call stack was unwound is neither visible nor relevant to the caller.

A quick demo can show that the stack traces are identical whether the exception is [caught and rethrown](http://ideone.com/O07IAh) or simply [allowed to propagate](https://ideone.com/7nqJY5).

> Is there any discernible overhead in using catchF instead of f?

The overhead of constructing the exception will far outweight any overhead of this redundant construct.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko can you provide an example of how? http://ideone.com/O07IAh vs https://ideone.com/7nqJY5, the stack traces are identical.

Comment: Unlike C# (where `throw;` is strongly recommended since `throw e;` trims stack trace and thus adds unwanted difficulties to debugging), `throw e;` is a good practice on Java. Nice catch! +1

Comment: "Typically, you rethrow a caught exception if you need to do some cleanup": using try-with-resources is better for doing cleanup.

Comment: Regarding this comment "The overhead of constructing the exception will far outweight any overhead of this redundant construct.", the construct is invoked even if an exception isn't thrown.

Comment: @Raedwald it is, provided your resources implement AutoCloseable. Things like Locks don't. And in any case, under the covers, this is (basically) what TWR is doing.

Comment: @AndyTurner I considered `catchF` as a whole, so I would be able to find it in the stacktrace. In your examples, it's unidentifiable

Answer (score 0):

An exception handler that simply rethrows and does not affect the known types of the exceptions has absolutely no semantic effect.

In theory, then, compilers or the JVM could optimize the try-catch out. In practice, I doubt that they do, because such code should be rare and not on hot paths (exceptions should never be); it's probably not worth the effort to implement such an optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm going to edit the question to add the use case (it won't affect your answer).

Comment: An exception handler that simply rethrows an exception, where that exception is the only one caught, has no semantic effect. In `try {} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { throw e; } catch (RuntimeException e) {}`, the `catch IAE` has a semantic effect.

Comment: BTW, I've added a use case for this.